# Updating to 4.4.3

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, android-versions, rom-update

I'm trying to update my Nexus 4 from 4.4.2 to 4.4.3 and every time the message pops up, I select install and clockworkmod recovery keeps saying error, installation aborted, STATUS 7. I've even tried doing toggle signature verification. I have the latest cwm, root, and I also have ROM manager installed. Does anyone know how to properly install this update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the stock recovery back and use that for the update, instead of trying to do it with CWM.

For a Nexus device, you can get the official factory images from [here](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images).  Download the Nexus 4 factory image for the Android version you're currently running (probably KOT49H) and unzip it.  Inside, one of the files is a `.zip` file.  Extract *that*, and you'll find a `recovery.bin` file.  Flash this to your recovery partition in the same way that you flashed CWM, and you'll have your stock recovery back.  (You can reinstall CWM when you're done.)

Remember to enable OTA survival in SuperSU, by the way, or you'll lose root when you install the update.

Comment: On my phone there is no stock recovery

Comment: Every Android device has a recovery.  It's what's used for system updates and factory resets.  When you installed CWM, you were putting it into the existing recovery partition, replacing the recovery that came with the phone.

Comment: my phone does not have a recovery. If you boot it into a recovery while theres no cwm it just gives you an error. I installed it using usb and a program on my computer (odin style)

Comment: The screen with the android in the middle and a red triangle above him?  That *is* the stock recovery.  It's not meant to be used interactively like CWM is; it expects the Android OS to have provided a script to tell it what to do automatically.

Comment: Well thats aomething new, thanks, but all that trouble espetially loosing both cwm and root in the end is just not worth it. Hell if i could i would downgrade to 4.3 cuz kitkat is horrible, glitchy, and uses up a lot of battery and i mean a lot. Samething happened to my old phone, it had 2.3 gingerbread and upgrading it made problems. Every phone should not be upgraded

Comment: Instead, i might even downgrade. Do you think i can downgrade with keeping all my files. Keeping them directly, not backing up and restoring cuz that never worked for me

Comment: FWIW, my Nexus 5 is doing fine with KitKat.  And 4.4.4 is a security update; you probably ought to install that.  SuperSU OTA survival worked fine for both the 4.4.3 and 4.4.4 upgrades on both my Nexus 5 and Nexus 10, so I expect it'll work fine on your Nexus 4 as well.

Comment: No its fine, this whole thing gave me the idea to downgrade, and i will try maybe installing the stock nexus 4 rom

Comment: Installing any factory image will wipe your data.